# How can I make sure text next to my checkbox never goes underneath the checkbox?

Tags: html, css

[image]

When the text is long the checkbox goes above the text. How can I make it stay on the same line as the text but break the text if its long? ie give the text `white-space:normal` but keep the checkbox and the first bit of the text on the same line.

```
 <input style="float: left" type="checkbox" ...etc..> <a href="...">my text</a>
```

Comment: Please provide an example of your code that makes this happen.

Comment: Are you looking for:  word-wrap: break-word; ?

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah I dont want the checkbox to be on a different line to the first part of the text. the text however can take multiple lines

Comment: @user521180, I updated my answer with something that may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've amended the markup to use a `label` and `input`, but that's not necessary (you'll just need something to contain your checkbox. Take a look at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/fZyeg/) for an example.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
     <label><input type="checkbox"> My text - this label can be as long as you want it to be, see?</label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 150px;
    background: red;
}

label {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 1em;
}

input {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -1em;
}
```

The width on the `.container` is just there to show that this will work when the text wraps: it will work at any width and for responsive designs without anything fixed. It'll look like this:

[image: Checkbox with long form label example]

And here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/mnFTF/) using your original markup (with an added `span`, I'm assuming you can include that):

```
<div class="container">
    <span><input type="checkbox"> <a href="#">My text - this label can be as long as you want it to be, see?</a></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that but I don't have a label. I have an anchor and checkbox. please have a look at my original post. I have updated it

Comment: I've added in a version using something more like your markup (you should be able to take that CSS and apply it where needed). The extra span containing both the input and anchor is needed - if you can't add that in you'll have to take a different approach such as @AnilkaBobo's by adding a fixed width.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:  Something else that maybe useful for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/persianturtle/FrEsX/3/

Hide's the overflow.

Something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/persianturtle/vwfwh/3/

If not, draw a picture.

```
.container {
width: 150px;
height: 200px
}

input {
margin: 25px 25px 50px 50px;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have added an image to my original post.

Comment: Try taking out the "float: left;" styling.

Answer (score 0):

well I would set fixed width for a.

```
a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px; /*whatever number you need*/
}
```

Comment: that didn't work. I have updated my original post. please have a look again

Answer (score 0):

You can try `&nbsp;` witch is for Non Breakable Space.